# create a mutable attribue with a defualt value?

Tags: rust

This [MWE](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=da4981397bc9746f716af4bfe3511d21) demonstrates how I can create a `struct` with an attribute that can be updated inplace. What I would like to do is extend this so that I can call `MyStruct::new(None)` and get a default value for the `.param` attribute. I tried numerous things along this line of thought:

```rust
    pub fn new(param: Option<&'a mut usize>) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        let tmp = param.unwrap_or(&mut 342);
        Ok(MyStruct { param: tmp })
    }
```

which, of course, does not work. The error is clear:

```rust
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
  --> src/main.rs:11:9
   |
10 |         let tmp = param.unwrap_or(&mut 342);
   |                                        --- temporary value created here
11 |         Ok(MyStruct { param: tmp })
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

However, I need some help actually resolving it.

Comment: your `Ok(MyStruct { param: tmp })` creates and references a temporary value. I think part of the answer is here https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#:~:text=Ownership%20of%20Struct%20Data

Comment: Try changing the fn def to `pub fn new<'a>(` to make the lifetime of the value the same of the struct and therefore it exists for the right amount of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in fact the raison is &mut not implement Clone and Copy trait and "tmp"
is owned by the "new" function.

What is the goal tht's "param" is declared mut?

This work

```
use anyhow::Error;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct MyStruct {
    param: usize,
}

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn new(param:  Option<usize>) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        let tmp = param.unwrap_or(342);
        Ok(MyStruct { param: tmp })
    }

    pub fn updater(&mut self, e: usize) {
        self.param = e
    }
}
```

This also

```
use anyhow::Error;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct MyStruct<'a> {
    param: &'a usize,
}

impl<'a> MyStruct<'a> {
    pub fn new(param: Option<&'a usize>) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        let tmp = param.unwrap_or(&342);
        Ok(MyStruct { param: tmp })
    }

    pub fn updater(&mut self, e: &'a usize) {
        self.param = e
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let mut x = MyStruct::new(None)?;
    println!("param = {:?}", &x.param);
    
    x.updater(&14);
    println!("param = {:?}", &x.param);
    
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! As for why `param` was mutable, that's where Clippy steered me when I was trying to get the MWE working. In fact, it really shouldn't be mutable.